# Are Django settings shared across uwsgi workers?

Tags: django, python-3.x, uwsgi

I have a Django app, with a setting (in my settings.py file) that's populated dynamically in my App Config's `ready()` function.  Ie in `settings.py` I have:

```
POPULATE_THIS = None
```

and then in apps.py in ready I have:

```
def ready(self):
    if POPULATE_THIS is None:
        POPULATE_THIS = ... some code which instantiates an object I need that's effectively a singleton ...
```

This seems to work ok.  But I'm now at the point where rather than just running the dev server locally (ie `python manage.py runserver`), I'm now running the Django app through uwsgi (proxied behind nginx), and uwsgi is configured to run 10 worker processes (ie my uwsgi ini file has `processes = 10` and `threads = 1`).

I'm seeing evidence that even though there are 10 uwsgi processes , `ready()` is still called exactly once on app startup and the value of `POPULATE_THIS` is the same across all workers (doing a str on it is giving the same memory address).

My question: How is that value shared across the uwsgi processes, as I thought separate processes are distinct and do not share any memory?  And am I correct in assuming that `ready()` is going to be called once per app startup (ie when uwsgi itself spins up), and not once per uwsgi worker process startup?

This answer ([Multiple server processes using nginx and uWSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028217/multiple-server-processes-using-nginx-and-uwsgi)) on a different question seems to indicate that some data is shared across workers, but I can't seem to find any official docs that indicate what exactly is shared and how, specifically with respect to Django settings, so some explanation/details would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not quite sure about the answer, just some thoughts: first, the fact that the var `POPULATE_THIS` points to the same memory address in every uwsgi process does not mean that they share memory since this address is virtual (not physical) and every process has the full (with exceptions) virtual memory adresses space available. One possible explanation for both of your observations would be that uwsgi forks the processes AFTER every app has been initialized. I don't know if that is the case but it could be...

Comment: As far as I know, that value can not be shared across processses, but your tests suggest otherwise. Maybe as @ivissani suggested, uwsgi may be forking processes after initialization. You can write a view method that assigns a random value to POPULATE_THIS and another one to return it, and call these methods several times through requests to see how they behave.

Comment: ^^ Great tip, I did this and what I'm seeing is it looks like it does fork the process, so each worker gets an independent *copy* of the settings.  If I update a settings value in one of the workers, that change isn't visible in the other(s).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly.

It seems that uwsgi only spawn processes of the django application itself, therefore all the functions `ready` will be called only once, during the first run.